# Convertir un objeto json a HTML, formateado

Tags: html, nodejs, pdf

El tema es que estoy creando un pdf con información recibida en json
solo quiero darle un formato para que se vea igual a un objeto json dentro de un html

Utilizo html-pdj para crear el pdf en NODEJS

EJEMPLO:

La respuesta de la url es:

```
 {
      tipo: 'reqres',
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'
 }
```

Si lo paso a string con JSON.stringify(data) se ve así en el pdf

```
 {tipo: 'reqres',url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'}
```

El temas es que obviamente quiero que se vea con el formato correspondiente en el pdf (como el 1).
La ayuda sería si hay una librería para formatear un objeto y pasarlo a html o simplemente tendré que crear una función para formatear el string ...

Gracias, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Encontrada, queda para experiencia en caso que alguien tenga la duda.
Encontré la solución y era tan simple como ver los argumentos que la función JSON.stringify().   Lo utilizo para imprimir un json en un pdf, específicamente con ésta librería ( html-pdf de nodejs) y quedaría... siendo `data` el objeto JSON

`let textFormateado = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
let cuerpoPdf = '<pre>${textoFormateado}</pre>'`

Cambiar la comillas simple por el ` para insertar una variable
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript

Comment: Puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada!